# minecraft command conversion from 1.9 to 1.14 help?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was looking for a way to make Christmas lights in vanilla Minecraft and found a fairly simple set of commands even a noob like me could execute. Unfortunately, they're heavily outdated. As I've said, I'm a pure amateur when it comes to commands, so I don't know how to convert it myself.

Essentially, its colored particles at the end of glass panes set to glow when a lever is flipped. It used floating invisible armor stands where the light was going to be and three command blocks, etc. etc.

I'll link the website I found the video and commands from. if there's a similar way or a conversion anyone could provide, I'll be eternally grateful.

[original website with 1.9 commands](http://www.theredengineer.com/working-christmas-lights.html)

Comment: I recommend googling "Minecraft 1.13 commands converter" (because that's where the most command changes were done) and seeing if that already does all you need. It wouldn't give you the prettiest or best performing commands, but hopefully ones that work.

Comment: Wow, that was a fast upvote! I hadn't even finished reading it through myself after sending!

Answer (score 2):

For the repeating command block, use:

```
execute if block <x> <y> <z> lever[powered=true]
```

and use these two in the two chain command blocks:

```
execute at @e[name=GREENLIGHT] run particle minecraft:dust 0 1 0 1 ~ ~ ~ 0 0 0 0.05 100

execute at @e[name=REDLIGHT] run particle minecraft:dust 1 0 0 1 ~ ~ ~ 0 0 0 0.05 100
```

in case you want to customize the color ot size, here is the syntax for the dust particle: `/particle dust <r> <g> <b> <size> <x> <y> <z> <width> <height> <length> <speed> <amount> (force|normal) (selector)` with the (force|normal) and (selector) being optional so I didn't include them in the commands.

to summon the armor stand, use:

```
/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {NoGravity:1,Marker:1,Invulnerable:1,CustomName:"\"GREENLIGHT\""}
```

make sure your chain command blocks are conditional for the lever detection to work properly.